# how to bind two multibinders with @Named but same interface type?

Tags: guice

We have a Multibinder and would like to have two so we need the @Named annotation so we can do

```
@Inject @Named("work")
private Set<Runnable> work;
@Inject @Named("otherWork");
private Set<Runnable> otherWork;
```

IS there a way to bind Multibinder with names?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this static factory](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html#newSetBinder%28com.google.inject.Binder,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation) and [this helper method](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html#named%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Multibinder<Runnable> multibinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(
    binder(), Runnable.class, Names.named("work"));
```